# summing all number belong the same group in a text file in python

Tags: python

I have a text file like this example:

```
fit c3 start=1455035 step=1
2.000000
2.000000
2.000000
2.000000
2.000000
2.000000
fit c2 start=5195348 step=1
1.000000
1.000000
1.000000
1.000000
1.000000
fit c4 start=6587009 step=1
10.000000
10.000000
10.000000
10.000000
10.000000
```

each text line(starting with fit) is followed by some number lines. I want to sum all numbers which are below each text line (so they are in the same group) and replace the first number of that group by the sum of number of that specific group and also replace the rest of numbers by 1.000000 - like in this output example:

```
fit c3 start=1455035 step=1
12.000000
1.000000
1.000000
1.000000
1.000000
1.000000
fit c2 start=5195348 step=1
5.000000
1.000000
1.000000
1.000000
1.000000
fit c4 start=6587009 step=1
50.000000
1.000000
1.000000
1.000000
1.000000
```

and write it into a new file.

I tried this code in Python, but actually did not return what I want.

```
lines = open("file.txt", "r").read().splitlines()
_sum = 0.
for i, line in enumerate(lines):
  if not line.startswith('fit') :
    _sum += float(line) 
    lines[i] = '{:0.6f}'.format(1.)

  if line.startswith('fit') and  i > 0:
    lines[i-1] = '{:0.6f}'.format(_sum)

with open('output.txt', 'w') as out:
    out.write(_sum)
```

Do you know how to do that in python?

Comment: you just need to write lines instead of _sum... and remember to joint the lines with newlines before wirting, something like `out.write('\n'.join(lines))`

Comment: but the point is that using this code the last number would be summation not the first.

Answer (score 0):

Just keep track somehow of which line is the first one of each block, and write `_sum` in that position.

For instance, I haven't checked, but something like this should work

```
lines = open("file.txt", "r").read().splitlines()
_sum = -1
last_first_line = -1
for i, line in enumerate(lines):
  if not line.startswith('fit') :
    _sum += float(line) 
    lines[i] = '{:0.6f}'.format(1.)

  if line.startswith('fit'):
    if last_first_line > 0:
        lines[last_first_line] = _sum
    _sum = 0
    last_first_line = i + 1
lines[last_first_line] = _sum

with open('output.txt', 'w') as out:
    out.write('\n'.join(lines))
```